# Navlistpanel shiny id messes with leaflet providertiles

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I'm trying to modularize my shiny app where a particular module is for displaying a map using leaflet library. I'm using navlistPanel to go sequentially from one module to another. But it looks like when I add id to the navlistPanel, the leaflet providertiles doesn't add the base-map and it messes up the functioning of other modules as well. Has anyone else faced this problem?

Here is the relevant chunk of code -

In the UI

```
    tabPanel("Analysis", icon = icon("bar-chart"),
                  navlistPanel(#id = "modules",
                    tabPanel("Upload",
                             value = "upload_module",
                             uploadUI("upload"),
                             DensityMapUI("DensityMap")                                                              
                    ),
                    tabPanel(...)
                    )
```

and in the server

```
     output$customer_density_map <- renderLeaflet({

coords <- fortify(map_data)
leaflet() %>% addProviderTiles(provider = providers$Stamen.TonerLite) %>%  setView(lng = mean(coords$long),lat = mean(coords$lat),zoom = 6) %>% 
  addPolygons(data = map_data,
              fillColor = ~color_pal()(N),
              fillOpacity = .5,
              color = "white",
              weight = 1) %>% 
  addLegend(position = "bottomright",pal = color_pal,values = map_data$N,opacity = 1, title = "Density Map")
})
```

The id in the navlistPanel is currently commented out. This renders the map to the output. But if I uncomment the id, then nothing showsup, not even other modules or any error or warning message.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! For us to help it would be good to proivide as much detail as possible about the issue. Error messages. Your code. Etc. You can edit the question to include this info.

Comment: I have added the relevant code chunks